# How can I change JavaScript Indentation on VSCode?

Tags: indentation, visual-studio-code, auto-indent

I want to do indentation like this.
(Arrays are not listed on one line, but on two lines.)

[image]

But in my VSCode, it does not indent like the picture below.

[image]

How do I set it up? The language is JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to user settings (by `Ctrl + ,`) and search for `editor.wrappingIndent`. Change the value to `indent` or `deepIndent`.

Answer (score 0):

For `wrappingIndent` to work,
We would need to give one of the below values for `wordWrap`:

```
"editor.wordWrap": "on",
"editor.wrappingIndent": "deepIndent"
```

OR

```
"editor.wordWrap": "bounded",
"editor.wrappingIndent": "deepIndent"
```

OR

```
"editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
"editor.wrappingIndent": "deepIndent"
```